Invalid host header error, on aws ssm remote host curl attempts
I'm working on integration with outside service. This service has restrictions only for whitelisted ip addresses that originates from US. I'm operating from Europe, and using VPN not an option in this case. I've established AWS EC2 with US based IP, which got whitelisted in the service.
For convenience of local development I wanted to have possibility to send requests from my local machine, through whitelisted EC2, to dedicated service. Problem is, that I'm not very experienced with those kind of operations, and I'm not 100% aware of the ways this can be established.
When I was researching web I found promising AWS resource:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-working-with-sessions-start.html#sessions-start-port-forwarding
I established it on my side with following:
aws ssm start-session \
  --target <machine-id> \
  --document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSessionToRemoteHost \
  --parameters '{"portNumber":["443"],"localPortNumber":["8088"],"host":["dedicated.host.com"]}'

I confirmed, that local port 8088 is running, and I checked with simple:
curl -k  https://127.0.0.1:8088
Which ended up with:
{ code: 1000, message: 'Invalid host header'}
I'm getting this response for every single endpoint I'm hitting in this outside service.
I'm curious what this error means, and if there is any walkaround for it. I assume, that this message is coming from service informing about conflict between hosts names, but as I mentioned I'm not very experienced in this, and I wasn't able to find any good explanation of it. Its not a matter of life or death for me, I will figure my way around development but this cluelessness is killing me.
